# Compile-time tracking of "value owner" with lifetimes

Tags: rust, lifetime

Is there any way to track value "owner" so that it passing it to other owners is a compile-time error? I've been looking into invariant lifetimes and the [`generativity`](https://docs.rs/generativity/1.0.1/generativity/) crate, but my rust-fu is not quite up to the task.

Code probably explains what I'm trying to do the best:

```rust
use core::marker::PhantomData;

// The lifetime `'a` is somehow only valid for the `Bar` that created `Foo`
#[derive(Default, Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a Owner>,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Owner {}

impl Owner {
    fn get<'a, 'b: 'a>(&'a self) -> Foo<'b> {
        Foo::<'b>::default();
    }
    
    // Somehow requires that the unique lifetime of `self` applies also to `Foo`.
    fn set<'a>(&'a mut self, _foo: Foo<'a>) {
        // whatever code
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut owner = Owner::default();
    let mut owner2 = Owner::default();
    
    let anon_foo = Foo::default();
    let foo2 = owner2.get();
    
    owner.set(foo2); // should not compile
    owner.set(anon_foo); // also should not compile
    
    owner2.set(foo2); // compiles!
}
```

This is a rather theoretical question, I'm not trying to solve a specific problem, just trying to see if such zero-cost abstraction construct is possible in Rust.

**EDIT:** This is not required to work in non-trivial cases, it just has to fail-safe (should never allow `set` if compiler cannot prove the `Owner` is the actual owner).
Also, the creation of the Owner struct can be with a macro, it doesn't have to be runtime constructable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of lifetimes, that have variance and weird rules, it would be easier to use a token type. You can create a local nested token type by using a macro, or requiring that the users specify the token manually.

This solution tracks the owner by its *creation point*, so if you create two owners in the same line of code, they will share ownership. Consider that a non-trivial case.

The code would be something like this:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    _pd: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}
//Default is only for anonymous Foo
impl Default for Foo<()> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Foo {
            _pd: std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

struct Owner<T> {
    _pd: std::marker::PhantomData<T>,
}
impl<T> Default for Owner<T> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Owner {
            _pd: std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Owner<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> Foo<T> {
        Foo {
            _pd: std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
    fn set(&self, foo: Foo<T>) {
    }
}

macro_rules! new_owner {
    () => {{
        struct Tok;
        Owner::<Tok>::default()
    }}
}
```

This code passes your test case perfectly fine:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..2 {
        vec.push(new_owner!());
    }
    let mut owner = new_owner!();
    let mut owner2 = new_owner!();
    let anon_foo = Foo::default();
    
    let foo2 = owner2.get();
    
    owner.set(foo2); // error
    owner.set(anon_foo); // error
    
    owner2.set(foo2); // ok!
}
```

The error emitted is something like:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:53:15
   |
53 |     owner.set(foo2); // error
   |           --- ^^^^ expected `main::Tok`, found a different `main::Tok`
   |           |
   |           arguments to this method are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected struct `Foo<main::Tok>` (`main::Tok`)
              found struct `Foo<main::Tok>` (`main::Tok`)
```

Since the token is build by the macro, if you somehow create both owners in the same macro call, it will compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut owners = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..2 {
        owners.push(new_owner!()); // just one macro invocation
    }
    let foo = owners[0].get();
    owners[1].set(foo); // OK, same token type.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not possible since you need actual code to make a type/lifetime. If you create a `[Owner]` (slice of `Owner`), every element will be the same type/lifetime.

Types are easy to make invariant: any regular type without generics or lifetimes is invariant, since there's nothing to vary over. Whenever you want a distinct type, you can simply `struct T;` and voila! This is essentially what makes [typemap](https://docs.rs/typemap) work. The only thing generativity does is allow you to make lifetimes that are the same way. You need something more restrictive: a new type/lifetime each time a function is called at runtime, which neither is capable of.

Comment: This is not required to work in non-trivial cases, it just has to fail-safe (should never allow `set` if compiler cannot prove the `Owner` is the actual owner).
Also, the creation of the Owner struct can be with a macro, it doesn't have to be runtime constructable. (Added also as edit.) Not sure if that changes anything, however.